# Youtube video description on colorbox

Tags: jquery, css

I am using [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) in one of my project to create a video gallery. And I want to get the video description under each video in opened colorbox modal. So far this is what I have,

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
  });
</script>
```

and the html;

```
<div class="utube-box">
 <a class='youtube' href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VOJyrQa_WR4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/VOJyrQa_WR4/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I couldn't find any options in colorbox, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colorbox doesn't handle grabbing external information as far as I know, so you have to get the information yourself and pass it. Pretty simple with some jQuery.

You'll probably want to clean up the CSS a little, but this is the general idea: http://jsfiddle.net/aQKHQ/1/

To break down the fiddle:

`$(".youtube").each( ...` Selects any links with a class of 'youtube'.

`var videoID = ...` Pulls the url from those links and filters out the video ID.

`var self = $(this);` is simply so we can access this link we're currently working on within the next part.

`$.getJSON( ...` Pulls the JSON data for the video from YouTube and calls Colorbox with the appropriate options.